# How do I get numbers of element from a JSON file with Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
  [
     {
       "dataset_id": "courses",
       "dept": "phys",
       "id": "301",
       "avg": 71.67,
       "instructor": "bryman, douglas",
       "title": "elec & magnetism",
       "pass": 146,
       "fail": 6,
       "audit": 0,
       "uuid": 441,
       "year": "2015"
     },
     {
       "dataset_id": "courses",
       "dept": "phys",
       "id": "301",
       "avg": 71.67,
       "instructor": "",
       "title": "elec & magnetism",
       "pass": 146,
       "fail": 6,
       "audit": 0,
       "uuid": 442,
       "year": "2015"
     },
     {
       "dataset_id": "courses",
       "dept": "phys",
       "id": "301",
       "avg": 73.07,
       "instructor": "louis-martinez, domingo",
       "title": "elec & magnetism",
       "pass": 113,
       "fail": 4,
       "audit": 0,
       "uuid": 5957,
       "year": "2013"
     }
   ]
```

Here is my JSON file and I intend to get a number of elements which is suppose to be 3. I tried to use:

```
    let num = JSON.parse(file).result.length;
```

I got a result of Syntax error says "Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0".
What did I do wrong?

Comment: What is `file`? Are you using node.js fs?

Comment: `let num = JSON.parse(file).length;` since you don't have a `result` property.

Comment: The error stated is unexpected token c in JSON at position 0. That might also be a problem, but doesn’t fix the code

Comment: Give the data a variable name, such as const txtFile = [ and then console.log(txtFile.length);

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide a bit more context on how you're getting "file". Is it from an ajax request, is it a static file in your project directory, etc.?

However, since you're using typescript im wagering it is a static file (client or server side shouldnt matter).

You'll probably need to just export it correctly. Add `export const variableName = [...]` and then you should be able to import it in any file via `import file from './filepath'`. You shouldnt need to `JSON.parse()` it.